# Project Euler #34: I cannot find the mistake in my solution

Tags: python, math

I am working on the following problem:

145 is a curious number, as 1! + 4! + 5! = 1 + 24 + 120 = 145.

Find the sum of all numbers which are equal to the sum of the factorials of their digits.

Note: as 1! = 1 and 2! = 2 are not sums they are not included.

This is my code:

```
import math


#upper bound taken from    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620877/project-euler-34-find-a-mathematical-approach-for-upper-bound
for x in range (1,2177281):
    #s refers to the sum of factors
    s=0
    for i in str(x):
        s=s+math.factorial(int(i))
        if s==x:
            print(s)
```

The return is:

```
>>>
1
2
145
40585
>>>
```

These numbers both work however I am clearly missing other values as well according to various online sources.

I do not need anyone to rewrite the code but if anyone could explain my logical mistake it would help.

Comment: Can you identify your "various online sources"?

Comment: What's the problem? It says find the sum of all numbers that follow the specified property. If you add your output up you get the right answer (excluding 1 and 2)

Comment: You shouldn't indent the `if s==x:` bit, but that turns out not to matter much in practice.  Those appear to be the only four base-10 [factorions](http://oeis.org/A014080).

Comment: @DSM beat me to it. You don't/shouldn't need to do the comparison in the nested loop.

Comment: Responce to Hans: Online source is http://www.s-anand.net/euler.html . It has been correct on all previous problems

Comment: @user5017397: your source says 40730.  40730 == 145 + 40585.  What's the problem?

Comment: Your program is right and the various resources you are talking about seems to be wrong except you need to pull out the `if` clause from the 2nd loop (nested `for`) and place it under the outer `for` loop. But the answer will remain irrevocably same vis-a-vis the source http://www.s-anand.net/euler.html you cited here. Ergo, the answer will be `145+40585=40730` which is concordant with the solution. :)

Comment: I am an idiot and forgot to add them up... I thought it was asking how many different numbers carry such properties. Thank you tanmaya and sorry for the dum question.

Comment: 1 up for calling yourself idiot :P and of course realizing your mistake. :) Don't be sorry. :) There is no such thing as dumb question if you really work on it, then ask it and rectify your mistake to find the solution; although mistake may be a small one (sometimes a small typo causes havoc in programs).

Answer (score 0):

The result you get is correct. There are only four numbers in that range that have this property: 1, 2, 145, and 40585.

You don't need to compare every digit of the number in turn inside the loop, comparing at the end is enough, i.e.:

```
import math

for x in range (3,146):
    #s refers to the sum of factors
    s=0
    for i in str(x):
        s=s+math.factorial(int(i))
    if s==x:
        print(s)
```